# Uncaught ReferenceError: Cliente01 is not defined at HTMLElement.onclick ---Como Enviar varchar en evento onclick JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

**Necesito Obtener el codigo de cliente que está en una tabla HTML y mostrarlo en una alerta.**
**Cuando el onclick Recibe un campo con valor Entero no hay problema; tengo una funcion que me muestra el valor en un Alert. Pero cuando Recibe un campo varchar - cliente codigo "C010"**

Al hacer clic en el botón me indica el siguiente error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: C010 is not defined
    at HTMLElement.onclick

**Este es el codigo que tengo con el evento onclick dentro de un ciclo for**

```
contenido += "<td>.......onclick='editsocio("+ data[i].CodigoM+")'>";
```

De antemano Muchas Gracias!

Comment: El valor debe estar entre comillas: `contenido += "<td>.......onclick='editsocio('"+ data[i].CodigoM+"')'>";`

Answer (score 0):

Gracias @Triby de esa forma ya había probado y me decia error de sintaxis.

Lo que hice fue quitar las primeras comillas y dejar solo las que envían el campo varchar.

Quedó de la siguiente forma:

```
contenido += "<td>.......onclick=editsocio('"+ data[i].CodigoM+"')>";
```